# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' after changing TCP/IP Port

Tags: mysql, port, localhost

When I change the TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
`port=3306` to `port=3808` in `my.ini`, my Django project works very well. Navicat also can login in to mysql with same user name and password.

But I can't login into mysql via the command-line. Logins to mysql give this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Even if I add `skip-name-resolve` to the `[mysqld]` block in `my.ini`. The error only disappears when I change the port back to 3306.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the command you're using to log in?

Try forcing TCP protocol:

```
mysql --port=3808 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```

Comment: It works,thank you! It's strange that mysql in command-line do not read the `my.ini` which I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

**[mysqld]** section is for your server while mysql cli uses **[client]** section

> The [client] option group is read by all client programs (but not by mysqld). This enables you to specify options that apply to all clients. For example, [client] is the perfect group to use to specify the password that you use to connect to the server

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)